# How do i fix this numbered history Error in python?

Tags: python

I have a code snippet:

```
for x, y in history.items():
  for i in llistr:
    print("||", i + ":", x, "=", y)
```

When i add something to the history, here's the output:

```
 1: 13+14 = 27
```

But when i add a new history entry:

```
2: 13+14 = 27
2: 13+15 = 28
```

The preferred output is:

```
1: 13+14 = 27
2: 13+15 = 28
```

How do I fix this? Sorry for being a noob, this is my first post.

Also, I can't use any libraries.

Full source code is here: https://github.com/bplx/Mathinator

How to reproduce: Use main.py, then use calculator once, check the history, then use calculator again, then check the history again.

Comment: What is `history`? What is `llistr`? We can't debug this without seeing the rest of your code. Also you can't bet getting the output you claim to be as you are printing the same `x` and `y` in the inner `for` loop.

Comment: Show a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as properly formatted code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use nested loops. Use `enumerate()` to get indexes in parallel with the items.

```
for i, (x, y)in enumerate(history.items(), start=1):
    print(f"{i}: {x} = {y}")
```

Comment: This only prints the last entry. I need a list of all entries, numbered in order.

Comment: What's in `llistr`? I didn't see it in your full code.

Comment: I see the link to github, but the code there doesn't have `llistr`.

Comment: I changed the answer to use `enumerate()` instead of `llistr`.